# How To keep web apps running in messaging menu?

Tags: notification, messaging-menu, notification-area

Ubuntu 12.10 introduced all sort of web apps, and some of them get added to the messaging menu.

My question however is the following. These web apps must remain open in a tab, for the messaging menu to keep count of your unread messages. Is there a way to keep the count  going, even with the tab closed?

A behavior similar to the music apps. Banshee remains open, even when you close window. but truly exit when you, specifically exit it.

[image]